# What is C in sklearn Logistic Regression?

Tags: scikit-learn, regularization

In `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`, there is a parameter `C` according to docs

> Cfloat, default=1.0
> Inverse of regularization strength; must be a positive float. Like in support vector machines, smaller values specify stronger regularization.

I can not understand it? What does this mean? Is it λ we multiply when penalizing weights?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as it says in the documentation; it's $1/\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the regularization strength.